Discrepancies in Loan Amortization Calculations between Excel and Python using numpy_financial
I'm developing a loan calculation application in Python and have implemented both French and Italian amortization methods using the numpy_financial library for calculating payments, interest, and principal. However, the results obtained from my Python calculations do not match the results obtained when replicating the same calculations in Excel, despite using the same conditions (interest rate, loan amount, duration, payment frequency) in both cases.
To be more precise: when I calculate the french amortization with those inputs:

Enter interest rate: 4.5
Enter loan term (in years): 10
Enter amount borrowed: 1500000
Choose amortization type (French or Italian): French
Choose payment frequency (monthly, quarterly, semi-annual, annual): annual


I get totally different results from the excel calculations with the .PMT function.
Here is the Python code I use to calculate the amortization schedule:
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy_financial as npf
import pandas as pd

class Loan:
    def __init__(self, rate, term, loan_amount, amortization_type, frequency, start=dt.date.today().isoformat()):
        self.rate = rate
        self.term = term
        self.loan_amount = loan_amount
        self.start = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(start).replace(day=1)
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.periods = self.calculate_periods()
        self.period_rate = self.calculate_period_rate()
        self.pmt = npf.pmt(self.period_rate, self.periods, -self.loan_amount)
        self.amortization_type = amortization_type
        self.table = self.loan_table()

    def calculate_periods(self):
        if self.frequency == 'monthly':
            return self.term * 12
        elif self.frequency == 'quarterly':
            return self.term * 4
        elif self.frequency == 'semi-annual':
            return self.term * 2
        elif self.frequency == 'annual':
            return self.term
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported frequency")

    def calculate_period_rate(self):
        if self.frequency == 'monthly':
            return self.rate / 12
        elif self.frequency == 'quarterly':
            return self.rate / 4
        elif self.frequency == 'semi-annual':
            return self.rate / 2
        elif self.frequency == 'annual':
            return self.rate
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported frequency")

    def loan_table(self):
        if self.frequency == 'monthly':
            periods = [self.start + relativedelta(months=x) for x in range(self.periods)]
        elif self.frequency == 'quarterly':
            periods = [self.start + relativedelta(months=3*x) for x in range(self.periods)]
        elif self.frequency == 'semi-annual':
            periods = [self.start + relativedelta(months=6*x) for x in range(self.periods)]
        elif self.frequency == 'annual':
            periods = [self.start + relativedelta(years=x) for x in range(self.periods)]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported frequency")

        if self.amortization_type == "French":
            interest = [npf.ipmt(self.period_rate, month, self.periods, -self.loan_amount, when="end")
                        for month in range(1, self.periods + 1)]
            principal = [npf.ppmt(self.period_rate, month, self.periods, -self.loan_amount)
                         for month in range(1, self.periods + 1)]
            table = pd.DataFrame({'Payment': self.pmt,
                                  'Interest': interest,
                                  'Principal': principal}, index=pd.to_datetime(periods))
            table['Balance'] = self.loan_amount - table['Principal'].cumsum()

        elif self.amortization_type == "Italian":
            interest = [self.loan_amount * self.period_rate]
            principal_payment = self.loan_amount / self.periods
            principal = [principal_payment]
            payment = [interest[0] + principal[0]]

            for month in range(1, self.periods):
                interest_payment = (self.loan_amount - (month) * principal_payment) * self.period_rate
                interest.append(interest_payment)
                principal.append(principal_payment)
                payment.append(interest_payment + principal_payment)

            principal[-1] = self.loan_amount - sum(principal[:-1])
            payment[-1] = interest[-1] + principal[-1]

            table = pd.DataFrame({'Payment': payment,
                                  'Interest': interest,
                                  'Principal': principal}, index=pd.to_datetime(periods))
            table['Balance'] = self.loan_amount - table['Principal'].cumsum()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported amortization type")

        return table.round(2)


Despite the implementation seeming correct, there are differences in the results when I compare the same calculations in Excel, in which the results are totally different (with Python I get - for the first period and an amortization method identical with the example
I provided - a payment of 6750000.27€, a principal (increasing over time) payment of 0.27€ and an interest payment of 6750000 euros; while in excel I get a (constant) payment of 189.568,23€, an initial (increasing over time) principal payment of 122.068,23€ and an interest payment of 67500€ that - however - is not correct in the subsequent periods since in my python code in the second period the interest payment is about 64.000€ while in my excel file is about 62.000€).
Can anyone help me understand what might be causing these discrepancies and how I can resolve them?
